# Moving points in Qt with mousePressEvent

Tags: c++, qt, qt4

I have implemented the mousePressEvent so that when you click on a point, it makes that point a different colour. Can anybody tell me what I have to put into the mouseMoveEvent so that the selected point moves with the mouse?

Answer (score 0):

You should keep your point's coordinates and update them accordingly in your `mousePressEvent` and call `update()` at the end of the method. Then you should paint your point in the paint event.